# Parallel stacks widget in visual studio code for debugging multi-thread C++ application

Tags: c++, visual-studio-code

In Visual Studio 2017 (and later), we can find this beauty for debugging multi thread C++ applications:
[image: Parallel Stack widget]

I could not find anything equivalent in Visual Studio Code.
Has anyone found anything similar, for a quick total view of the stacks of the threads?

Comment: It already has that? VSCode shows callstack for each thread, although it doesn't have these pretty popups

Comment: I know it can show callstack for each thread, i am searching on how to see all threads on a single place